# Intel classic compiler reports non-unit strided load in simple assignment

Tags: c++, vectorization, simd, memory-alignment, icc

Consider the following loop, where I initialize an (aligned) array of complex numbers and would like to default-initialize them. I want to make use of SIMD for the sake of speedup:

```cpp
constexpr auto alignment = 16u;
struct alignas(alignment) Complex { double re; double im; };

// ...

constexpr auto size = 32u;
auto* cv1 = static_cast<Complex*>(aligned_alloc(alignment, size));

#pragma omp simd
#pragma vector aligned
for (auto i = 0u; i < size; ++i) {
    cv1[i] = Complex{0.0, 0.0}; // THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC LINE
}
```

I am using `#pragma omp simd` to generate SIMD instruction and also Intel's `#pragma vector aligned` to indicate that my memory is aligned.
If I enable vectorization reports, the compiler displays the following message ([see here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/E3z3qohvd)):

```
remark #15328: vectorization support: non-unit strided load was emulated for the variable <U5_V>, stride is 16
...
remark #15475: --- begin vector cost summary ---
remark #15476: scalar cost: 108 
remark #15477: vector cost: 119.500 
remark #15478: estimated potential speedup: 0.900 
remark #15485: serialized function calls: 1
remark #15488: --- end vector cost summary ---
...
remark #15489: --- begin vector function matching report ---
remark #15490: Function call: ?1memset with simdlen=4, actual parameter types: (vector,uniform,uniform)   [ <source>(26,9) ]
remark #26037: Library function call   [ <source>(26,9) ]
remark #15493: --- end vector function matching report ---
```

Apparently the non-unit strided load hampers proper vectorization and the estimated speedup is less than 1.
Now let's write the loop like this:

```cpp
constexpr auto zero = Complex{0.0, 0.0};
#pragma omp simd
#pragma vector aligned
for (auto i = 0u; i < size; ++i) {
    cv1[i] = zero;
}
```

Instead of assigning `Complex{...}` within the loop, I create a constant first and then assign it within the loop ([see it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/M55ssK9no)).
Now the compiler reports:

```
remark #15475: --- begin vector cost summary ---
remark #15476: scalar cost: 6 
remark #15477: vector cost: 1.500 
remark #15478: estimated potential speedup: 3.910 
remark #15488: --- end vector cost summary ---
```

which is what I would expect for such a simple loop.

Can anyone explain why this happens? Shouldn't the results be identical for both cases?

What I understood so far is that the compiler tries to be smart and sees that `cv1` could be replaced by a call so `memset`, which seems to impair optimization (quick verification: replace 0.0 by some other number). Is there a way to disable this "optimization"?

Comment: How is this related to my question? Note that this is an excerpt from a much bigger code base, I cannot easily replace the data structures here. Moreover, I am trying to understand what is happening in this specific example.

Comment: It's not about compiler optimizing the loop to a `memset`, it's about the compiler failing to optimize the `Complex{0.0, 0.0}` to a `vxorpd` and hoist it out of the loop. That is what the compiler is complaining about - that it has to load the synthesized `Complex` value from the stack on every iteration. If you move the initialization out of the loop, then the compiler is smart enough to convert it to a `vxorpd` and has no reason to complain about the loop.

Comment: And BTW, you can see in the assembler that the compiler doesn't actually call `memset` in neither of the cases, so that transformation is a red herring.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/a6zbE4Eb4

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @AndreySemashev. Re the `memset`: My assumption was that the call to the underlying (presumably SIMD-aware) implementation is inlined and thus not visible in the code. Why would the report be mentioning `memset` otherwise? Also, do you have any idea if there could be a way to ensure the compiler optimized the `Complex{..}` variant as well? From your explanation it seems like there's not much hope :/

Comment: @andreee Most of modern memset implementation's will use SIMD internally.  I.e. if compiler has SIMD e.g.  MMX, SSE, AVX or anything like that for ARM etc  optimization options compiler usually use memset implemented with this SIMD instructions. For sure for GNU Lib C++ and MS CRT used by ICC and ICX. Source code of both libraries is open and you can easily check assembly code your self.

Comment: AFAIK, icc is effectively dead at this point and replaced with the clang-based icx. So yeah, chances of this ever being fixed are close to zero. You can see icx generates a more efficient code: https://godbolt.org/z/MYzaMsb3v.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. Unfortunately I am still stuck with icc right now. Anyhow, thanks for the enlightenment. I guess that for now the proposed workaround will be necessary then.